# Where is my m2 folder on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: maven-2, osx-mavericks

I cant seem to find the local .m2 folder on Mac OS X mavericks. Ideally it should be at `{user.home}/.m2` but I cant seem to find it.

Should I create it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you have used brew to install maven, create .m2 directory and then copy settings.xml in .m2 directory.

```
mkdir ~/.m2
cp /usr/local/Cellar/maven32/3.2.5/libexec/conf/settings.xml ~/.m2
```

You may need to change the maven version in the path, mine is 3.2.5

Comment: For m1 Mac, the maven installed by `homebrew` would be in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar`

Comment: So for m1 and m2 chips (with homebrew) the full path is: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.4/libexec/conf/settings.xml`

Answer (score 39):

On the top of the screen you can find the Finder. Click `Go -> Go to Folder -> search ~/.m2`

If it is not found, as `m2` is a hidden file you need to enable visibility by typing the following command in terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17979006)

Comment: @NigamPatro Actually, it *does* answer the question. It answers the title "Where is my m2 folder on Mac OS X Mavericks" (as well as the implicit question in the body of the post) by showing *how* to find it, just like two of the other answers. It also implicitly answers the question "Should I create it?", i.e. -> if you can't find it by doing a proper search for it, then it doesn't exist, and if you need it then by all means create it!

Comment: If you can't see hidden files in MAC's Finder, simply press SHIFT + CMD + . (dot)

Answer (score 33):

Go to finder:

Press on keyboard CMD+shift+G .  [it will show u a popup like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A43O.png)

Enter path ~/.m2

press enter.

[image]

Comment: It also works when you want to open the files inside this folder in IDEs

Answer (score 17):

It's in your home folder but it's hidden by default.

Typing the below commands in the terminal made it visible for me (only the `.m2` folder that is, not all the other hidden folders).

```
> mv ~/.m2 ~/m2
> ln -s ~/m2 ~/.m2
```

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/5198803)

Comment: Does this not just instead move default-hidden ~/.m2 to visible ~/m2?  If so, this isn't the same as making the former ~/.m2 visible.

Answer (score 13):

If you search directly it won't appear so please follow as below steps to see .M2 repository path.

```
Go-> Find folder ->  type this "~/.m2" and click go
```

If Maven is already installed and used, the .m2 will be listed.

[Source](http://selenium2testing.blogspot.com/2015/10/where-is-m2-folder-maven-repository-on.html)

Comment: This duplicates the earlier Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348840/1357094

Answer (score 8):

By default it will be hidden in your home directory. Type `ls -a ~` to view that.

Answer (score 8):

On mac just run `mvn clean install` assuming maven has been installed and it will create .m2 automatically.

Comment: I was looking for this option as I didnt want to create a folder manually and probably run into the issues of setting access for users and groups using chmod.

Answer (score 7):

You can try searching for local .m2 repository by using the command in the project directory.

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository
```

your output will be similar to below and you can see local .m2 directory path as shown below: /Users/arai/.m2/repository

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/jtidy/jtidy/r938/jtidy-r938.jar (250 kB at 438 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar (335 kB at 530 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.jar (305 kB at 430 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar (500 kB at 595 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar (621 kB at 671 kB/s)
[INFO] No artifact parameter specified, using 'org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1' as project.
[INFO]
/Users/arai/.m2/repository
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.540 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-23T13:57:54-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep '.m2'`

Answer (score 5):

1. Open your terminal
2. Type `open ~/.m2`

It will open .m2 folder in explorer

Answer (score 3):

Go to your root folder

```
Shift + Command + .
```

press this then you can see all the hidden files. Because your .m2 file suppose to be a hidden folder