# Local maven repository location

Tags: java, spring, maven

I installed Maven 3.3 using mac's brew tool. I am not able to find the location of the .m2 folder. Please help me finding that folder.

I ran the following command to install Maven:

```
brew install maven@3.3
```

**Edit**:

[Where is my m2 folder on Mac OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496131/where-is-my-m2-folder-on-mac-os-x-mavericks)
In the above link it is mentioned, I have to manually create `.m2` folder. But, ideally it should be automatically created like in ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes maven should automatically create .m2 folder
Did u install some artifacts go mvn local repository after mvn installation ?

Comment: Yeah, this duplicates [Where is my m2 folder on Mac OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496131/where-is-my-m2-folder-on-mac-os-x-mavericks).  Even with the edit in this question.

Comment: It should be automatically generated when downloading dependencies of a maven project.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ubuntu then you can find `.m2` (hidden folder) folder into `home` directory. path : /home/username/.m2

if you are using Windows system, then .m2 folder is expected to be located under ${user.home}. On Windows 7 , 8, 10 this resolves to \Users\. So you'd normally see it under c:\Users\maven.m2.
.

Answer (score 0):

Maven create automaticaly the .m2 folder :

It's in your home foldder , you didn't see it coz it's hidden by default .

you can tape those cmd tu make it visible :

```
> mv ~/.m2 ~/m2
> ln -s ~/m2 ~/.m2
```

Answer (score 0):

If used brew to install maven, create .m2 directory and then copy settings.xml in .m2 directory.

> mkdir ~/.m2
>
> cp /usr/local/Cellar/maven32/3.1.5/libexec/conf/settings.xml ~/.m2

You may need to change the maven version in the path