# spring boot stater parent 2.0.1 entityManagerFactory Bean creation exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting following error when I change my `spring boot stater parent 1.5.9 RELEASE` to `2.0.1 RELEASE`

target/surefire-reports

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.restapispringboot.RestApiSpringbootApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.158 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.restapispringboot.RestApiSpringbootApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.restapispringboot.RestApiSpringbootApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
```

**Could it be something in my config that I need to change to make it work?**

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boot_rest_api
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create


logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

Application main

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.restapispringboot.repo")
@EntityScan("com.restapispringboot.model")
public class RestApiSpringbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApiSpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
   // getters and setters
}
```

Repo

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

**Update**
I just notice when I `mvn clean install`  I also get the following errors.  But I checked my build path both JRE[JavaSE-1.8] and maven dependencies are build path...

```
ERROR] error reading /Users/erichuang/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.13/aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading /Users/erichuang/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.22.0-GA/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Comment: Everything else seems fine but spring.jpa.database-platform value should be just MYSQL instead of dialect classname. Also, do you need to specify @EnableJpaRepositories, @EntityScan?

Comment: you mean `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` should just be `MYSQL`?  I specify @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan because I have seen tutorials like this so I just thought I need it.... does Spring-boot automatically take care of this?

Comment: Your exception says java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile. May be there is some conflict in javaassist jar.Could you clean your maven repo and run it once again?

Comment: @Unknown Thank you.... Your suggestion made it work....  you can answer this question and I will mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your error says,  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile`.

As you were migrating from spring boot version `1.5.9 RELEASE` to `2.0.1 RELEASE`, there might be some conflict in the `javassist` jar `(3.20.0-GA vs 3.22.0-GA)`.

So you can clean your maven repo (delete the localRepository)  and run your command once again.

Comment: This is for people who were wondering. To clean your maven... you can `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false`  However this didn't work for me.  I had to go in to my ~/.m2 and delete the repo.  Here is how if any one was wondering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496131/where-is-my-m2-folder-on-mac-os-x-mavericks?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa