# Java packages storage location

Tags: java

I am new to Java and just downloaded Eclipse and wrote my first Hello World program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Whats your name?");

        String userName = myObj.nextLine();
        myObj.close();

        System.out.println("Hello " + userName);
    }

}
```

I was wondering what the storage location  of the package java.util is? Where is this package stored on my computer? I use Mac.

Comment: Your question actually does not need your hello world example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disclaimer

In java the libraries are .jar files, **not packages**. A package is just a folder used to groups the class. I mean package is not a file.

Javas code is compiled into .class files. One of that .class is Scanner.java. Usually the .class files are grouped in a jar file.

### Core or default libraries

Any internal or core library is inside of JDK or JRE which was configured on your eclipse:

[image]

Depending of your configuration, usually you cannot see the source code of **java.util.Scanner** because it is compiled as **.class** and is inside of a .**jar** file. Some jdk or jre distribution has the source code :

[image]

**On Linux**, I found that class in the rt.jar located in **../jre/lib** inside of the open jdk

[image]

### Public libraries

This is the case when you are working with some library created by the community like: apache, spring, jackson, etc

In this case, maven download the library in the .m2 folder inside of the user folder of your os.

### Java is open source

If you want to take a look in the source code, you will find it on github or google searching: "java.util.Scanner java"

- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java
- https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java
- https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157040/3957754
- [Where is my m2 folder on Mac OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496131/where-is-my-m2-folder-on-mac-os-x-mavericks)
- https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/managing-jre-installations-in-eclipse
- https://mvnrepository.com/
- https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK
- https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html

Comment: The source code can also be viewed if one presses `ctrl` and then clicks on the class name.

Comment: *Where is this package storaged on my computer? I use Mac.* This would depend on your version of Java. In module-based JDKs/JREs it would be in java.base.jmod. In my case that's /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java16-amd64/jmods/java.base.jmod

Comment: In java the libraries are .jar files which contains .class files. One of that .class is Scanner.java