# Spring boot library class not importing error

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies

I am using BCryptencode class from springboot security library it s works fine for me but after i added to the github when cloning the repository its keep asking me to import the class path i checked With many different versions of security dependancy as well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPkVc.png)

I tried with different versions of security dependancy

Comment: Go to Users home directory, .m2/org/springframework/security folder and delete folder with given version and rebuild or force Maven update

Comment: Can you specify more how to find this folder in mac m1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348840

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything at last, I was hopeless and i had only one more option i reinstalled the ide in the that solved my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).